# Powershell: search subfolders and run script on each subfolder that contains file1.txt and continue searching

Tags: powershell-2.0

I am looking for a bit of help on a script that :

Would search in sub folder and every time it would find a WIM file, it would update it with the latest updates from wsus. When that script is finished then it would continue with next subfolder.

Here you have the code i had so far:

```
$thismonth = (get-date).AddMonths(0).ToString("yyyMM")
$lastmonth = (get-date).AddMonths(-1).ToString("yyyMM")  
$2ndlastmonth = (get-date).AddMonths(-2).ToString("yyyMM")  
$date = get-date -f "yyyMM"
$LogName = "wim_update_$($thismonth).log"
$UpdatesPath = "d:\WSUS\WsusContent\*"
$MountPath = “d:\temp\mount”
$folder = Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\Distribution\Operating Systems"
########### DISM Mount path ########
Set-Location "d:\Distribution\Servicing\x86\"

forEach ($os in $folder)
{
    ###########Alias########
    $WimFile = “d:\Distribution\Operating Systems\$os\sources\install.wim"
    Write-Host $WimFile

    if (-Not (Test-Path ($Wimfile))) { continue }

    ########### Backup WIM File######## 
    Copy-Item "d:\Distribution\Operating Systems\$os\sources\install.wim" -Destination "d:\backup\install-$os-$thismonth.wim"
    if (-Not $?)
    {
        Write-Host "Failed to copy WIM file"
        continue
    }

    ./DISM /Mount-Wim /WimFile:$WimFile /index:1 /Mountdir:$MountPath
    if (-Not $?)
    {
        Write-Host "Failed to mount WIM file"
        continue
    }

    ############ Apply updates
    $UpdateArray = Get-Item $UpdatesPath | where{$_.extension -eq ".cab"}
    ForEach ($Updates in $UpdateArray)
    {
         ./DISM /image:$MountPath /LogPath:d:\Temp\$LogName /LogLevel:3 /Format:List /Add-Package /Packagepath:$Updates
         Start-Sleep –s 10
    }
    Write-Host "Updates Applied to WIM" -foregroundcolor red -backgroundcolor yellow

    ./DISM /Commit-Wim /Mountdir:$MountPath

    ########### DISM : Unmount WIM file ######## 
    ./DISM /Unmount-Wim /Mountdir:$MountPath /commit
    ./DISM /Cleanup-Wim
}


###########Remove N-2 ######## 
#Remove-Item "d:\backup\$os\install-$os-$2ndlastmonth.wim"
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you looking for *help* with a script, or are you looking for someone to write the whole thing for you?

Comment: And in what way does this not work for you?

Comment: Actually, it worked now, I had some tipo mistakes. But very slow so I am trying to find a way to have the WIM files quicker updated. Because this current process is taking me +- 15 hours for updating 4 WIM files. Any idea's in how updating these WIM with the latest hotfixes?

Comment: That's a separate question you should be posting.